# How to refresh only a Textview of item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I have a `RecyclerView` with a list of `Product` which contains Image,Text, and a `CountDownTimer`, I call an Interface CallBack for each seconds changed from my `Product` class to my `Adapter`. I need to refresh only one `TextView` of my layout but `notifyItemChanged` call `onBindViewHolder` and it refresh all the data of my item. What is the best way to refresh only one TextView of an item ?

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolderCustom holder, final int position) {
        final Product currentProduct = listProduct.get(position);
        holder.productBrand.setText(currentProduct.getBrand());
        holder.productName.setText(currentProduct.getName());
        holder.productPrice.setText(currentProduct.getPrice());
        holder.time.setText(String.valueOf(currentProduct.getTime()));
        String urlImg = currentProduct.getPicture();
        Log.v("adapter", "item " + position);
        if (!urlImg.equals("empty")) {

            imageLoader.get(urlImg, new ImageLoader.ImageListener(){...});
        }
        if (currentProduct.getId() == 1 && test == 0) {
            test = 1;
            currentProduct.Start_countDown(new Product.TimeCallBack() {
                @Override
                public void timeCallback(Product product) {
                    int index = listProduct.indexOf(product);
                    notifyItemChanged(index);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: First use `equals` instead of `!=`

Answer (score 2):

`notifyItemChanged(position);` is the correct method if you want to redraw the entire item. When you have a large image for the background, even when cached, you will see some flickering if you call `notifyItemChanged` too quickly on the same item.

For your use case you only need to redraw one view so you can just update it directly like this:

```
public void updateTime(ViewHolderCustom holder) {
    holder.time.setText(String.valueOf(currentProduct.getTime()));
    holder.time.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: But this blinks... There is this blinking animation that is annoying

Answer (score 1):

```
It will notify the particular position rather that whole list,  

  @Override
    public void timeCallback(Product product) {
      listProduct.set(position, product);
     notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace new data at specific index in list and notify adapter with `notifyItemInserted` :

```
@Override
public void timeCallback(Product product) {
  listProduct.add(position, product);
  notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to add an object in my list , i need to print my countDownTimer for each seconds but i can not use notifyItemChanged because it refresh my image each second